# Using unique short and double value

Tags: c, windows, numbers

I have a C array of shorts and an array of longs. I want to be able to define when one of the array slots is not able to be filled by a function that calls it because there is insufficient or missing data. The valid values in both cases can be positive or negative, but I can safely assume that the values will never come close to the maximum value that can be placed in a short or a double.

This is a Windows 64-bit app, and I have been using `SHRT_MAX` as the short unique number. My questions are:

1. What is the equivalent of `SHRT_MAX` that I could use for `double`?
2. Is there a better way of doing this rather than resorting to `SHRT_MAX` and `double` max?

Comment: How large is this array? You could always consider having another array of flags of the same length, or a bit-vector, to indicate which elements in the array are valid and which are not. If you can guarantee that the values won't get near `DBL_MAX` (the chance of that exact value as opposed to another is fairly tiny anyway) then I guess you could stick with your method. I always like to be safe than sorry though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the maximum value to indicate a *null* parameter in the array. This is a common technique and is totally valid.

As for the max double, you want `DBL_MAX` from `<float.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

The macros are there for exactly the reason you are using them - so this is good (and portable)

Have a look at `DBL_MAX`

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use `DBL_MAX` from float.h or `numeric_limits<double>::max()`

2) Using the maximum values seems fine as long as you're sure that they will never be "normal" values. Otherwise you could use a little object that knows whether the number was changed:

```
struct Input
{
    short value;
    bool isTransformed;

    Input() : value(0), isTransformed(false) {}
};
```

Comment: I think the OP's using C, not C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a signaling NaN (`numeric_limits::signaling_NaN`). That way, if somebody tries to use it, they will take a floating point exception.